# How to get module name by class in Java 9?

Tags: java, java-9, java-module

How to get module name by class in Java 9? For example, let's consider the following situation. There are two named modules - ModuleA and ModuleB. ModuleA knows nothing about ModuleB. ModuleB requires ModuleA.

ModuleA contains class:

```
public class ClassA {

    public void printModuleName(Class klass) {
       //how to get here name of the module that contains klass?
    }
}
```

ModuleB contains class:

```
public class ClassB {

    public void doIt() {
        ClassA objectA = new ClassA();
        objectA.printModuleName(ClassB.class);
    }
}
```

How to do it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To get a **[`Module`](http://download.java.net/java/jdk9/docs/api/java/lang/Module.html)** by a **[`Class`](http://download.java.net/java/jdk9/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html)** in Java9, you can use the [`getModule()`](http://download.java.net/java/jdk9/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getModule--)

```
Module module = com.foo.bar.YourClass.class.getModule();
```

and further [`getName`](http://download.java.net/java/jdk9/docs/api/java/lang/Module.html#getName--) on the `Module` class to fetch the name of the module

```
String moduleName = module.getName();
```

---

An observable point to note (not in your case as you're using named modules) is that the **`getModule`** returns the module that this class or interface is a member of.

> - If this class represents an array type then this method returns the Module for the element type.
> - If this class represents a primitive type or void, then the Module object for the `java.base` module is returned.
> - If this class is in an unnamed module then the unnamed Module of the class loader for this class is returned.

Comment: I came from OSGi and I think OSGi - use framework to get bundle by class.